# selenium in python browser.find_element_by_name('submit').click() not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape a site that needs login information, and after hours of trying to figure out why I keep getting "Login failed", I believe it is simply because the "Log in" or "Submit" button is not actually getting clicked. I realized this by saving a screenshot of the browser right when it "fails". My username and password are filled into the fields.

I've tried things like `wait`, `elementScrollBehavior`, nothing seems to work. I'd really appreciate some help with this! Code below.

```
def load(self):
    global browser

    DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS["elementScrollBehavior"] = 1
    #browser field
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    #browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    #browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    loginId = self.id
    password = self.pw
    browser.get('https://link.example.com')
    browser.find_element_by_id('cf-login').send_keys(loginId)
    browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
    browser.find_element_by_name('submit').click()
    #wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "crefli_HC_SSS_STUDENT_CENTER")))
    try:
        if browser.find_element_by_id('crefli_HC_SSS_STUDENT_CENTER'):
            #return login status
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        print('element not found on page')
        print(browser.current_url)
        #browser.save_screenshot('~/Desktop/screen2.png')
```

HTML of form:

```
    <form name="loginform" action="/oam/server/auth_cred_submit" method="post">

<div class="nonfloat-box">
Username:
<input type="text" id="cf-login" name="username" class="username inputbox" autocomplete="OFF">
</div>

<div class="float-box">
Password:
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="password inputbox" autocomplete="OFF">
</div>
<input type="image" src="https://www.cuny.edu/site/citizencuny/cunyfirst-login/loginbutton.jpg" onclick="javascript: return signon_validate()" alt="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I believe I need to SOMEHOW get that bit of javascript to run. But HOW?

UPDATE: Selenium has a submit() method that automatically submits the `<form>` in HTML. Even using this, it does not work. As you can see in the HTML, it IS a form. At this point I do not know what else to try.

Comment: can we see the site html?

Comment: this is going to be next to impossible to troubleshoot without the exact requests you're making

Comment: the site is: https://ssologin.cuny.edu/cuny.html?resource_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhome.cunyfirst.cuny.edu%252Fpsp%252Fcnyepprd%252FEMPLOYEE%252FEMPL%252Fh%252F%3Ftab%253DDEFAULT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, hope it helps

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element_by_name('submit').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
                 (or)
driver.find_element_by_name('submit').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is needed to make a more accurate determination, but I usually use enter key to submit forms, sometimes javascript messes up the ability to submits by click and a simple enter usually does the trick

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def load(self):
(...)
   browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
   browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
(...)
```

<s>Otherwise, make sure you mean `find_element_by_name` and not `find_element_by_tag_name`.</s>

Comment: I think theres absolutely zero reason this shouldn't work, but for some reason it still does not work. I really don't know what the issue could be. For some reason it just won't submit the login credentials. Im stumped.

Comment: @shmob maybe try it with chrome or firefox with a display and try to see what is going on.

Comment: when i use the chrome webdriver, chrome opens blank

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling `'submit'` is not being found by `find_element_by_name`. Try `find_element_by_xpath(//*[@name='submit'])`

Comment: I'm getting invalid syntax, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you use selenium do automatic testing  or  scraping ，I suggest  you use the method

```
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathString)
```

because you can check the xpathwebbroser's console 
Try this command  on console:

```
$x('xpathString')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath, Please try this

```
//input[@name='submit']
```

or

```
//input[contains(@name,'submit')AND contains(@alt,'Submit')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `submit()` to submit the form. It needs to be sent to the `<form>` tag

```
browser.find_element_by_id('cf-login').send_keys(loginId)
browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
browser.find_element_by_name('loginform').submit()
```

If this doesn't work you can use JavaScript click as a work around

```
submit = browser.find_element_by_name('submit')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)
```

You can also try sending `Enter`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser.find_element_by_id('cf-login').send_keys(loginId)
password_field = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
password_field.send_keys(password)

password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#OR
password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: does not seem to be working. I was hoping this would be the answer!! :(

Comment: i tried doing `print browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)` and it gave me 'None' -- any idea?

Comment: @shmob `execute_script` returns the value returned from the script. `click()` doesn't return any value, so you get `None` in the print.

Comment: Oh ok. Still, does not submit the form. Really don't understand.

Comment: @shmob Add another option to the answer.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @shmob I added another solution to my answer, the last (third) code block.